# Use ModelBinder for int array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinder

I have an method in my controller (SurfaceController which is a specific Umbraco controller):

```
public class ProductListController : SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult GetCategoryProducts([ModelBinder(typeof(IntArrayModelBinder))] int[] categoryIds, int page = 1, int pageSize = 10)
    {
        int total = 0;
        var products = ProductService.GetCategoryProducts(categoryIds, page, pageSize, out total);

        return View("/Views/PartialView/ProductList.cshtml", products);
    }
}
```

I then have the following ModelBinder, so I can create the request like "?categoryIds=1,2,3,4,5" instead of the default behaviour "?categoryIds=1&categoryIds=2&categoryIds=3&categoryIds=4&categoryIds=5".

```
public class IntArrayModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value
            .AttemptedValue
            .Split(',')
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

This also means that it doesn't work when I send int[] as parameter to RenderAction, but it works when join the values to a comma delimited string.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetCategoryProducts", "ProductList", new { categoryIds =  new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, pageSize = 50 }); }

@{ Html.RenderAction("GetCategoryProducts", "ProductList", new { categoryIds = string.Join(",", new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }), pageSize = 50 }); }
```

Can I somehow make it work with both int[] and string (split to int array for each comma), except changing "categoryIds" parameter in GetCategoryProducts to a string and then in this method split the string to an int array.

I would like if I can keep the signature GetCategoryProducts method.

Comment: Your could always check in the `IntArrayModelBinder` is the value can be cast to `int[]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you have an example of this? I can add `if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(int[])) {
                var array = value.RawValue as int[];
                return array;
            }` before return value in the example above, but then it doesn't work when requesting the method with categoryIds as a comma delimited string.

Comment: This is probably not ideal, but it works when sending `int[]`and comma delimited string to the method.
`if (value.AttemptedValue == "System.Int32[]") {
                var array = value.RawValue as int[];
                return array;
            }`